# How to break/escape from inner loop in Swift

Tags: swift, control-flow

I'm looking for a way to stop iterating the just inner loop once a condition is met. I thought of using "continue" but it's not doing what i wanted. 
"break" seems to break the entire loop including the outer loop.

So in my code, once the condition is met. I want to stop iterating j but i want to start iterating i again. Thank you,

```
for i in 0..<sortedArray.count{
        for j in 1..<sortedArray.count{
            if sortedArray[j] == sortedArray[i]{
                //I want to skip iterating inner loop j from now. and back to iterating i
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `break` just breaks the inner loop and *not* the outer one.

Comment: Seems like what you want to do is for j in i..<sortedArray.count{

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Break just breaks the inner loop.

e.g.

```
for var i in 0...2
{
    for var j in 10...15
    {
        print("i = \(i) & j = \(j)")
        if j == 12
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output -->

```
i = 0 & j = 10
i = 0 & j = 11
i = 0 & j = 12
i = 1 & j = 10
i = 1 & j = 11
i = 1 & j = 12
i = 2 & j = 10
i = 2 & j = 11
i = 2 & j = 12
```

Comment: For OP, one place you can easily check this is in the XCode Playground.

Comment: It was written in the playground.. :D

Answer (score 0):

The nested index loop and subsequent element access by index approach (`anArray[accessByThisIndex]`) is kind of C++'ish rather than Swifty. Depending on you application, you can make good use of neat features in Swift to achieve your goal.

E.g., assuming (based on the anme of your array) your array is sorted,

```
let sortedArray = [2, 5, 7, 9]

for i in sortedArray {
    for j in sortedArray where j <= i {
       print(j)
    }
    print("-----")
}

/* 2
   -----
   2
   5
   -----
   2
   5
   7
   -----
   2
   5
   7
   9
   ----- */
```

Note that we don't care about the indices of the array above, instead accessing the elements of the array directly in the `for ... in (... where ...)` loop(s).

---

Another alternatively coulkd make use of [prefixUpTo(:_)](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#func-prefixupto_)

```
for i in 1...sortedArray.count {
    sortedArray.prefixUpTo(i).forEach {
        print($0)
    }
    print("-----")
}

/* same printout as above */
```